# ylim with negative floating point number

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, floating-point

Could someone explain me why the following code compile perfectly :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd, 1000 sep={}, assume math mode=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4cm,
height=4cm,
ymin=-0.5,
ymax=0,
]
\addplot [forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
    5   -0.000535\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

while if I want

```
ymin=-0.1,
```

it does not compile anymore. Error message :

```
Missing $ inserted.
```

Clues for a possible answer :

- if the math mode is removed, the compilation is possible in both cases. But I dont want to remove it.
- if I have `ymin=-0.1` and `ymax=0.5`, it compiles too ...

Well ... I dont understand.

Comment: Why do you need `assume math mode` ?

Comment: im using it elsewhere on my document ;-) maybe i can remove it and adapt the document, but this is not the point here :-(

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Adding `yticklabels={}` to the axis options seems to remove the error. This seems related to the automatic computation of ticks or ticklabels in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt fails, because PGFPlots changes the way the `ytick`s/`yticklabels` are drawn when you change `ymin` to `-0.1` (see left plot). And this of course cannot be drawn in text mode, because in text mode neither `\cdot` nor `^` are known/can be interpreted.

To circumvent this problem you can change the number format of the `yticklabels` "back" to `fixed` (see right plot). (Optionally you can move the `yticklabel style` part to the preamble as well.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            1000 sep={},
            assume math mode=true,
    }
\begin{document}
% dummy plot to show where the problem is coming from
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=4cm,
        height=4cm,
        ymin=-0.1,
        ymax=0,
        % don't assume math mode
        /pgf/number format/assume math mode=false,
    ]
        \addplot table {
            5   -0.000535
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% plot showing how to circumvent the problem
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=4cm,
        height=4cm,
        ymin=-0.1,
        ymax=0,
        % change number format to `fixed'
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
%            % (optionally change the `precision' to your needs)
%            /pgf/number format/precision=2,
        },
    ]
        \addplot table {
            5   -0.000535
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Exactly what i was waiting for as explanation ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need `assume math mode=true` for this specific `tikzpicture`, you can pass `/pgf/number format/assume math mode=false` to the `axis` environment options or to the `tikzpicture` environment options to avoid the error.

Comment: another good solution in deed ! But i fact i spent one our to understand that the problem was coming from the math mode, i dont really understrand why it behaves like that ...

Comment: Maybe more advanded users as @marmot could answer that more precisely, but try to plot something almost empty may be the reason...

Comment: I dont think this is the reason because the problem appeared with a 
 huge figure ;-)